# Running model failed: Invalid argument: Only additions of two arguments supported. Num inputs: 4

Tags: ios, iphone, tensorflow

I was about to build a image semantic segmentation ios app. So I build the graph using the network architecture of deeplab, however,

I got this error :

```
Running model failed: Invalid argument: Only additions of two arguments supported. Num inputs: 4
     [[Node: fc1_voc12 = AddN[N=4, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](fc1_voc12_c0/BiasAdd, fc1_voc12_c1/BiasAdd, fc1_voc12_c2/BiasAdd, fc1_voc12_c3/BiasAdd)]]
```

The error occurs since iOS TensorFlow API does not support Add more than 2 tensors, while I got 4 tensors add together in the computing graph. Could anyone give some hints about how to implement it in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `tf.add_n([a, b, c, d])` use `tf.add(a, tf.add(b, tf.add(c, d)))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  I change the add_n to add operator, and use two intermediate variable for the sum of two tensors. But this error keeps showing in tensorflow ios version.

Comment: Then there is another add_n operation in there somewhere. Maybe the library adds it? Can you use the op name to find out what code can be adding it?

Comment: Thank you Alex, I wrapped the add operator, so anywhere uses it should be add instead of add_n. I think may be tensorflow building the graph by merging the intermediate node thus resulting the add_n? [link](https://github.com/DrSleep/tensorflow-deeplab-resnet/blob/master/deeplab_resnet/model.py)

Comment: That's likely. Can you inspect your graphdef to see where the add_n is coming from?

Comment: yes, the error messages show that anywhere uses add all being add_n, but only adding four tensors together will the error occur.